# How to double click NotifyIcon and open Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, notifyicon

I am using the library of [NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon). So far I have managed to create a TaskBarIcon using the next code:

```
TaskbarIcon tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("NotifyIcon");
```

And at the App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon" IconSource="icoLogo.ico" ToolTipText="Test test">
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>
            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" Opacity="0.8" Width="160" Height="40">
                <TextBlock Text="Test test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip> 
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
</Application.Resources>
```

On the Closing window event, i set the next code to hide the window:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Utils.Utils.pointOfSale = this;
        Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

I save the instance of the actual window to show it again when the task bar icon is double clicked, but how can i perform this using the App.xaml?

I tried the method mentioned on the tutorial link above, but it didn´t worked. I created this c# class:

```
class ShowWindowCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Utils.Utils.pointOfSale.Show();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

But when i try to hook up this command with the task bar icon:

```
<local:ShowWindowCommand x:Key="WindowCommand" />
```

It gives me an error that the command doesn´t exist in the namespace. So i added this line to the header of App.xaml

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BundyPOS.Utils"
```

Here is my project hierarchy:

[image]

It shouldn't be any problem, but for some reason Visual Studio is complaining about not finding the class.

Please, any information about double clicking the task bar icon and opening the program window using NotifyIcon will be helpful.

Comment: Your `ShowWindowCommand` is not public. Make it public.

Comment: Use Behavior (InvokeCommandAction) in your App.xaml and associate it with TaskBarIcon.